# Can't connect to PostgreSQL in Windows Server

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to upgrade my version of PostgreSQL to 9.2 on a Windows Server OS and I keep getting the following error:

```
 An error has occurred:
 Error connecting to the server: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

How do I make it not do this and actually connect like it is supposed to?  I'm using the exact same password from my older installation.

Comment: What are the steps you are taking to produce this error? Are you able to connect via PSQL?

Comment: I just installed the database and tried configuring it.  No, I am not able to connect.

Comment: Am I correct to assume you used the download from EnterpriseDB? Also what version did you download?

Comment: Also, try connecting with no password: `psql postgres`

Comment: Yup, got it from EnterpriseDB.  I have version 9.2.1.

Comment: Also, still no luck when I do it with no password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the installer via EnterpriseDB prompts you for a password during the initial setup - This password is the postgres users password:

[image]

If you do not remember the password, or if you typed it incorrectly during the install(twice!) [try these steps:](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#I_lost_the_database_password._What_can_I_do_to_recover_it.3F)

- edit pg_hba.conf to allow trust authorization temporarily
- Reload the config file (pg_ctl reload)
- Connect and issue ALTER ROLE / PASSWORD to set the new password
- edit pg_hba.conf again and restore the previous settings
- Reload the config file again

The files will be located in C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\data if you installed to the default path.

You can reload the configuration via PhAdmin III by right clicking on the server name and choosing reload configuration or use `pg_ctl reload`. Barring that restart the service or reboot.